# Consolidate mysql columns with duplicate values but some columns are null

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to consolidate data from three columns in mySQL.  This is a simplified example of teh data structure:

```
 Payment     EmpId1     EmpId2    EmpId3

  $25.04      345         345       x
  $12.34      123           x       x
  $89.76      999           x      999
```

Where x = 'Null'

I would like to have a single column of the EmpId that looks something like

```
  Payment      EmpID

   $25.04       345
   $12.03       123
   $89.76       999
```

My challenge is how to consolidate information across three columns when there is sometimes an EmpID, other times not.  I tried a CASE statement but that delivered unsatisfactory results.  Can this be accomplished in mySQL or should it be done in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
select coalesce(EmpId1, EmpId2, EmpId3) as EmpId, payment from table
```

But there may be other more elegant solutions.